# Insert values to db with iterations

Tags: php, mysql

so here I'm trying to make an insert function which will be dynamic. By dynamic I mean that it can insert into any table and **n** number of columns. I'm making this function so that I don't have to write multiple functions to insert whenever I have to insert into different table or increase number of columns.

In my function, I'm passing **2** parameters. One is the **tablename** and second is the array of columns and their values in this way.

```
$arr = array("customerid" => "123", 
              "email" => "asa");
```

And here's my function :-

```
function insert_tester($table,$arr)
    {
        global $conn;
        $val=0;
        try
        {
            $s = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(" . foreach($arr as $column => $valule) {$column.","} . ") 
                                VALUES(" . foreach($arr as $column => $value) {':val'.$val++} . ")");
            $val=0;
            foreach($arr as $column => $value)
            {
                $s->bindParam(":val$val", $value);
                $val++;
            }
            if($s->execute())
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }//function
```

But unfortunately my function doesn't work, it says foreach not expected.

What would be the best and right way to achieve my target ?

Comment: As a side note you really should try to stay away from passing a DB connection around as a global. Look into building a DB singleton class, it's a much neater solution

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't use `foreach` as an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually created a class that extends PDO just so that I could do what you want to do. Use this class instead of PDO when you instantiate your database connection. Then, you'll be able to use the insert, update, and delete methods directly on the database connection instance (i.e. `$conn->insert('sometable', array() );` ).

I use this class quite frequently and thought you might appreciate the bonus methods besides `insert($table, $data)`:

```
class DatabaseConnection extends PDO {

    public function insert($table, $data) {

        $fields = implode(", ", array_keys($data));
        $questionMarks = rtrim( str_repeat("?, ", count($data)), ", ");
        $stmt = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($fields) VALUES ($questionMarks)");
        foreach (array_values($data) as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($key+1, $value);
        }

        //return $stmt;
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function update($table, $data, $conditions) {

        $fields = implode("=?, ", array_keys($data))."=?";

        foreach ($conditions as $column => $condition) {
            if (empty($whereClause)) {
                $whereClause = "$column=?";
            } else {
                $whereClause .= " AND $column=?";
            }
            $data[] = $condition;
        }

        $stmt = $this->prepare("UPDATE $table SET $fields WHERE $whereClause");

        foreach (array_values($data) as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($key+1, $value);
        }

        //return $stmt;
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

    public function delete($table, $conditions) {

        $data = array();

        foreach ($conditions as $column => $condition) {
            if (empty($whereClause)) {
                $whereClause = "$column=?";
            } else {
                $whereClause .= " AND $column=?";
            }
            $data[] = $condition;
        }

        $stmt = $this->prepare("DELETE FROM $table WHERE $whereClause");

        foreach (array_values($data) as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($key+1, $value);
        }

        //return $stmt;
        return $stmt->execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't need to bind values, just pass them during `execute()`, see also my answer for that.

Comment: Btw, it's nicer to use composition here, i.e. have PDO db as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you exactly need, here $db is your PDO database connection object

```
function insert_tester($db, $table, $arr) {
    $fields = array_keys($arr);
    $values = array_values($arr);
    //build the fields
    $buildFields = '';
    if (is_array($fields)) {
        //loop through all the fields
        foreach ($fields as $key => $field) {
            if ($key == 0) {
                //first item
                $buildFields .= $field;
            } else {
                //every other item follows with a ","
                $buildFields .= ', ' . $field;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //we are only inserting one field
        $buildFields .= $fields;
    }

    //build the values
    $buildValues = '';
    if (is_array($values)) {
        //loop through all the fields
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 0) {
                //first item
                $buildValues .= '?';
            } else {
                //every other item follows with a ","
                $buildValues .= ', ?';
            }
        }
    } else {
        //we are only inserting one field
        $buildValues .= ':value';
    }

    $prepareInsert = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(' . $buildFields . ') VALUES (' . $buildValues . ')');

    //execute the update for one or many values
    if (is_array($values)) {
        $prepareInsert->execute($values);
    } else {
        $prepareInsert->execute(array(':value' => $values));
    }
    //record and print any DB error that may be given
    $error = $prepareInsert->errorInfo();
    if ($error[1]) {
        print_r($error);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using PDO, there's an easier way:

```
$names  = join(',', array_keys($arr));
$values = substr(str_repeat(',?', count($arr)), 1);
$s = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ($names) VALUES ($values)");
if ($s->execute(array_values($arr))) {
    return true;
}
```

This assumes your array keys and `$table` are valid table or column names in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try an implode on the keys

```
implode(', ', array_keys($arr));
```

And for your bindParms you can be clever and try

```
implode(', :', array_keys($arr));
```

You'll have to prefix the first one but that should get you on the right track